# Derive equation for shear modulus $G=E/(1+2v)$

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, finite-element-method

shear modulus, G young's modulus, E and Poisson's ratio, $v$:

$G=E/(1+2v)$

I have always wondered how this relation is derived, but have never found a derivation that I could follow online.

I assume it begins with drawing a distorted square and finding the change in distortion, but I haven't been able to successfully derive this myself. Can one of you lay out the steps for me, in all of the literature I own this equation is simply presented as is with no explanation. I am asking this question because I am currently studying the Finite Element method applied to elastostatics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have better luck with this in the physics forum.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I was beginning to think the same thing! Thank you for the advice.